# MySQL - Select with WHERE on LEFT Join table

Tags: mysql

I am making select from 3 tables, cases, calculactions and positions. From positions i need to devide results with one more parameter and it is repairmethod. Code below looks fine, and actualy it also display me results but without this repair method filter.

current code and results of text looks like:

```
 SELECT c.vin, c.case_id, c.axrmrs_id, c.date_created, 
    cl.totalcosts, cl.laborhours, cl.calculationdate, cl.laborcosts, 
    group_concat(DISTINCT po.text) as text 
    FROM axnmrs_cases AS c 
    LEFT JOIN axnmrs_calculations as cl on c.case_id = cl.case_id 
    LEFT JOIN axnmrs_positions as po on c.case_id = po.case_id 
    WHERE c.vin='U5YFF24128L064909' 
    GROUP BY c.vin, c.case_id, c.axrmrs_id
```

result (just partt with text)

```
        -------------------------------
        |   id  |      text           |
        -------------------------------
        |   2   |  text1,text2,text3  |
        -------------------------------
        |   3   |  text4,text5,text6  |
        -------------------------------
```

How it should looks like:

```
    --------------------------------------------------
    |   id   |      textA       |        textB       |
    --------------------------------------------------
    |   22   |   tex1, text2    |       text3        |
    --------------------------------------------------
    |   23   |      text5       |       text4        |
    --------------------------------------------------

   textA = SELECT text FROM axnmrs_positions WHERE repairmethod LIKE 'L%'
   textB = SELECT text FROM axnmrs_positions WHERE repairmethod LIKE 'E%'
```

I try something like, how ever I can't make it work:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN po.repairmethod = E THEN po.text) AS 'E'
```

Is there a chance someone can help me with this?

EDIT:
Fiddle linke: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a76e9/3

Comment: could you provide sqlfiddle with some data?\

Comment: hi @Alex on my way  to do it

Comment: It seems like E is not defined here: MAX(CASE WHEN po.repairmethod = E THEN po.text) AS 'E'. Or you just forgot quotes.

Comment: @Alex Fiddle added :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT ...
   , ...
   , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(po.repairmethod LIKE 'L%',po.text,NULL) ORDER BY 1) AS textA
   , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(po.repairmethod LIKE 'E%',po.text,NULL) ORDER BY 1) AS textB
   , ...
```

The first argument in the `IF` expression is evaluated as a boolean, if it's true, the second argument is return, otherwise the third argument is returned. And GROUP_CONCAT will ignore the NULL values. I also included an ORDER BY within the GROUP_CONCAT to make the return more deterministic.

If you are familiar with ANSI SQL: the `IF` function is essentially shorthand for a `CASE` expression. For example, this:

```
  IF(a,b,c)
```

is equivalent to:

```
  CASE WHEN a THEN b ELSE c END
```

So this:

```
  IF(po.repairmethod LIKE 'E%',po.text,NULL)
```

is equivalent to:

```
  CASE WHEN po.repairmethod LIKE 'E%' THEN po.text ELSE NULL END
```

(The CASE expression does let us omit the `ELSE NULL` if we want.)

Comment: interesting way how to do it @spencer7593,

Comment: Obviously, there are other patterns that can return an equivalent result, but this this approach is usually the most efficient.The `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY 1` are optional. The "trick" is really that `IF()` (or `CASE`) expression that conditionally returns `po.text` or a NULL.

Answer (score 2):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a76e9/9

```
SELECT c.vin, c.case_id, c.axrmrs_id, 
cl.totalcosts, cl.laborhours, cl.laborcosts, 
group_concat(IF(po.repairmethod LIKE 'E%',po.text, null)) E,
group_concat(IF(po.repairmethod LIKE 'A%',po.text, null)) A,
group_concat(DISTINCT po.text) as text 
FROM axnmrs_cases AS c 
LEFT JOIN axnmrs_calculations as cl on c.case_id = cl.case_id 
LEFT JOIN axnmrs_positions as po on c.case_id = po.case_id 
WHERE c.vin='U5YFF24128L064909' 
GROUP BY c.vin, c.case_id, c.axrmrs_id
```

Comment: Thank you alex, incredible how fast you guys know the answer. Thumb up for it.